# Encapsulated/Namespaced CSS and Sass Extend without Nested Selectors

Tags: css, namespaces, nested, sass

Considering that `Sass`' extend feature does not allow for nested selectors. What is a robust way to write modular and namespaced `Sass` while still making use of `Sass`' extend feature.

E.g. I do not wish to pollute my "global" name space with descriptor like class just so I can use `Sass`' extend feature.

```
.button { ... }
.my-widget .large-button { @extend .button; }
```

Additionally, the following does not work by design:

```
.my-widget .large-button { ... }
.your-widget .your-button {
  @extend .my-widget .large-button;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sass`' extend feature will not extend nested selectors but it does work within a scope.

E.g.

```
.my-widget {
  .button { ... }
  .large-button { @extend .button; }
}
```

Now the descriptor class `.button` is not found in the "global" space and is name spaced to `.my-widget`.